# How to Add Node to Tree View Dynamically?

Tags: c#, xml

how we can add node to tree view dynamically in c#

Comment: What kind of tree view? And I presume from your title you want to add an XML node? How is the data displayed now? Show some code if you want some help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the WinForms TreeView, see [Adding and Removing Nodes with the Windows Forms TreeView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984278%28VS.71%29.aspx)